# React: Bind number input to state (handle intermediate values)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a number stored in my React state, and I want to edit it using an `<input type="number" />`. Here's my attempt:

```jsx
function MyNumberInput() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(42);

  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      value={number}
      onChange={event => {
        setNumber(parseFloat(event.target.value)); // Convert string value to a number!
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[Try it on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/PullJosh/t86nzjsv/)

The problem is that **this code fails during intermediate, non-number states.** If I want to enter `-12`, I begin by typing the negative sign. When I do, the `onChange` handler fires, `parseFloat("-")` returns NaN, and the input remains empty. As a user, it feels like my input was completely ignored.

Comment: `parseFloat` is unnecessary, please remove

Comment: Is parsing actually required? ```parseFloat``` is being used in some edge cases I believe.

Comment: @iamhuynq `event.target.value` is a string, even for an input with type="number". I want to save a number in state.

Comment: You can also use setNumber(Math.trunc(event.target.value))

Answer (score 0):

1. You may want to **remove** the below props to enable non-number content input.

```
type="number"
```

2. And remove the `parseFloat` to store the string like `-` or `.0`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={number}
        onChange={event => {
          // console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
          setNumber(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Try it online:

[image: Edit charming-sun-nyye3]

Comment: This doesn't solve the original problem. I need the input to allow temporarily storing non-number values like `-` or `.`. This is required so that users can type `-12` or `.5` uninterrupted.

Comment: @PullJosh Answer updated, kindly check it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

just use unary plus operator to convert a string into a number like this:

```
function MyNumberInput() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(42);

  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      value={number}
      onChange={event => {
        setNumber(+(event.target.value)); // Convert string value to a number!
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use RegEx

The problem is the `input` get `NaN` is because the `input` type="number" and `-` or `.` is not a number.

I suggest to use RegEx:

```
function MyNumberInput() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(42);

  const updateNumber = ({ target }) => {
    const reg = new RegExp('^[0-9+-/]+$|^$');
    if (reg.test(target.value)) setNumber(target.value);
  };

  return (
    <input type="text" value={number} onChange={updateNumber} />
  );
}
```